# Cannot set a string as a key for my hashtable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set this string as my key:

```
a -long " string that - has. double and single quotes and dashes and dots
```

This string is the product of String Builder ToString() method.

The Hashtable is initialized like this: `$myHashtable = @{ }`

This is the error: **Cannot convert value "stringAbove" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."**

I tried escaping the double quotation marks with a backtick. But got still the same error.

```
$resultFromToString = $myBuilder.ToString()
$myHashtable[$resultFromToString] = @{
  One = $one;
  Two = $two;
}
```

Comment: Why is tagged with C# and .NET?

Comment: Did you `$myHashtable = @{}` before trying this?

Comment: Can you also show how you've created `$myHashtable`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The following hashtable gets created without issue: `@{ 'a -long " string that - has. double and single quotes '' and dashes and dots' = 'some value' }`. Did you forget to initialize your hashtable with `$myHashTable = @{}` first, or define the initial keys and values inline like in my example?

Comment: Nigel Bess already pointed out, but for future reference, please use only the tags that correspond with the language in question

Comment: Thank you for showing you've initialized the hashtable. I've voted to re-open. But the problem it seems may be something in the rendered `StringBuilder` string; I still can't reproduce this using the same key I used before. Can you share a redacted version of your key?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest, the implication is that some _intervening code_ following the initialization with `@{}` - which  isn't shown - accidentally changed what is stored in `$myHashtable` (assigned an _array_ instead).

Comment: I wanted to rule out some funky issue with hashtable keys, but I agree it seems like something is probably overwriting the assignment with an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message implies that **`$myHashtable` contains an *array*, not a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)**.

- To determine the actual type of `$myHashtable`, execute `$myHashtable.GetType()` or 
  `Get-Member -InputObject $myHashtable`

This example shows that there's no problem with your string, given that **a string with *any* value - even `''` - can serve as a hashtable key**:

```sh
$myHashtable = @{} # Initialize.

$myHashtable['a - long string that has " and '' quotes and - and .'] = 'foo'

$myHashtable # Output
```

Output:

```sh
Name                           Value
----                           -----
a - long string that has " an… foo
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

By contrast, if `$myHashtable` is an *array* (irrespective of the type of its *elements*), your symptom surfaces, with *any* string value (that can't be converted to an integer), given that **only *integers* can serve as array indices**:

```sh
$myHashtable = @{}, @{} # !! ARRRAY (of hashtables)

$myHashtable['some key'] = 'foo' # !! FAILS
```

Error output:

```sh
Cannot convert value "some key" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Note that, as the error message hints at, PowerShell automatically tries to *convert* a string index to an integer, so that something like the following *does* work, perhaps surprisingly:

```sh
# Same as: 
#   $myHashtable[0] = 'foo'
# because PowerShell automatically converts to [int]
$myHashtable[' -0 '] = 'foo'
```

Comment: @jsnoobie, I see that you just accepted (thanks), so I assume the problem is solved. Generally, note that unless you type-constrain variables in PowerShell (e.g., `[int] $num = 42`), they're free to change their type with any subsequent assignment. Both `$myHashtable = @{}` (as in my first snippet) and `$myHashtable = [hashtable]::new()` work, as long as you don't assign an instance of a different data type later, before attempting the index operation (`[...]`). Note that you should prefer `@{}` to [hashtable]::new()`, because the latter create a case-_sensitive_ hashtable.